# Raspberry Pi 3 does not boot if not connected to ethernet cable

Tags: ssh, ethernet, cmdline.txt

I'm new here, so I'm sorry if I started an already existing thread.
I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie (2017-06-21). It has SSH enabled. I just modified my cmdline.txt to set static IP.
cmdline.txt looks like this:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1
root=PARTUUID=2f542d6a-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline
fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
ip=192.168.1.200::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off
```

The ssh connection works fine on my laptop. The `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0 iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1 iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug usb0
auto usb0 
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.42.42
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.42.0
broadcast 192.168.42.255
```

I modified this file in order to SSH using USB Tethering, that works fine as well. It, however, does not work if I just boot up the Pi without the Ethernet connection.

I also made a music player using python which works, but not on boot. I used rc.local but that doesn't help. That also works if the ethernet cable is plugged in. Earlier (I don't remember which version of Raspbian I had) it worked fine.

I have also noticed a change in the earlier and the new cmdline.txt files.

You can see the music player at my blog - http://sparkthatplug.blogspot.com

YouTube - http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF-1-bnmCXpKdTfkKkoxnaA

Comment: Your `network` file is totally messed up: make sure to have correct line ends. As it is, it doesn't parse correctly.

Comment: And how do i fix it? @TheDiveO

Comment: It now looks better. Now, decide on a single place where to put the static configuration to; I highly recommend using only `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Thus, remove the `ip=` boot parameters (why are you doing this after all?), and remove the static configuration form `/etc/network/interfaces`. Set `iface usb0 inet auto` as I assume(?) that your wired LAN has a dedicated DHCPv4 service running on a home router or something similar. In `dhcpcd.conf` set for `interface usb0` then `static ip_address=192.168.42.42/24`.

Comment: Please add information about your network structure to your question; without such important information it is yet unclear what you are trying to achieve. Is there a home router with DHCPv4 and default route present?

Comment: @TheDiveO  i understand the part of removing the ip= part from the cmdline.txt but if i do that i cannot connect to the pi in anyway, even if i put the ip= thing back in the file the ssh connection is not possible

And im sure you explained in a perfect way but i'm not sure about what to do next
how do i configure the dhcpcd.conf file or the interfaces file

and about the router -  i want to make that thing portable so why do you ask about the router (yes i do have a router to use, just in case)